# ng-Grid error when getting focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm having a problem with ng-grid that I can't figure out. Whenever I click on a cell I get this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid.debug.js:3494:21
at h.$get.h.$broadcast (http://localhost:8080/carsweb/dist/js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:103:414)
at ngGridDirectives.directive.focusOnInputElement (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid.debug.js:2989:20)
at HTMLDivElement.focus (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.11/ng-grid.debug.js:3034:21)
at http://localhost:8080/web/dist/js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:27:15
at Array.forEach (native)
at q (http://localhost:8080/web/dist/js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:7:255)
at HTMLDivElement.c (http://localhost:8080/cars/dist/js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:26:492)
```

Here is the code for the grid:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
                data: 'appLogData', 
                enableCellSelection: true, 
                enableRowSelection: false, 
                enableCellEditOnFocus: true, 
                columnDefs: [{field: 'appKey', displayName: 'appKey', enableCellEdit: true}, 
                             {field: 'appKeyGroup', displayName: 'appKeyGroup', enableCellEdit: true}, 
                             {field: 'appKeyValue', displayName: 'appKeyValue', enableCellEdit: true}]
        };
```

I'm not sure if somehow the libraries of angular.js and the ng-grid could be conflicting somewhere? I'm not quite sure how to debug this so any tips on that or what might be going wrong would be appreciated, thanks.

**Update**

Here's a quick glace at the appLogData that I am using for the grid:

[image: appLogData]

Versions: 
ng-grid v2.0.11
angular.js v1.2.4

I think the error is something to do with the field getting the focus, I've seen some posts on changing the edit template and the COL_FIELD being wrong in the templates but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: To reproduce this error it would also helpful if you tell us the ng-grid version and show us your json data. Everything in your example looks good for me.